# Decrypt/Verify signed data using public certificate asp.net

Tags: asp.net

My client has signed the xml in Java using private key & IAIK tool. I want to decrypt/verify the data in ASP.NET 2.0. I have public certificate of my client. I have tried various methods but verifcation fails. Kindly suggest any code to verify/decrypt the data. The signed XML is as follows

```
<TrnResponse>
 <Transaction>
  <Type>TrnResponse</MessageType>
  <ReferenceNo>123456</ReferenceNo>
  <ClientName>ABCDI</ClientName>
  <TReferenceNo>111111</CTReferenceNo>
  <Mode>05</Mode>
  <Status>SUCCESSFUL</Status>
  <TRXDateTime>06-03-2012 13:16:21</TRXDateTime>
  <TRXID>001111222</TRXID>
  </Transaction>
 <Signature>  <SignatureValue>MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIIHlwIBATELMAkGBSsOAwIaBQAwCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcB</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
</TrnResponse>

i am trying following code to verify

    XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
            Doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
            Doc.Load(@"d:\data.xml");
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(Doc);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

            X509Certificate2 cert = GetRecipientCert(); // method returns public certificate
            RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;

            string publickey = cert.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(false);

            XmlNodeList xn1 = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("Transaction");
            string license_code = xn1.Item(0).OuterXml.ToString();
            ASCIIEncoding ByteConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] verify_this = ByteConverter.GetBytes(license_code);
            string base64_encoded_signature = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("SignatureValue").Item(0).InnerText;
            byte[] signature = Convert.FromBase64String(base64_encoded_signature);
            bool ok = csp.VerifyData(verify_this, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(), signature);

Please help to solve this
```

Comment: You need to paste the Java side signing code. Otherwise, it is hard to tell if your C# verifying code is correct or not

Comment: Hi, the java code is with client. they don't want to share same. Please help me